# MySQL 1064 error, works in command line and phpMyAdmin; not in app

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, node.js, dbslayer

Here is my query:

```
select * 
  from (select *, 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN(RADIANS(45.5200077 - lat)/ 2), 2) + COS(RADIANS(45.5200077)) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) * POWER(SIN(RADIANS(-122.6942014 - lng)/2),2))) AS distance 
          from stops 
      order by distance, route asc) as p 
group by route, dir 
order by distance asc 
   limit 10
```

This works fine at the command line and in PHPMyAdmin. I'm using [Dbslayer](http://code.nytimes.com/projects/dbslayer/wiki) to connect to MySQL via my JavaScript backend, and the request is returning a 1064 error.

Here is the encoded DBSlayer request string:

> http://localhost:9090/db?{%22SQL%22:%22select%20*%20from%20%28select%20*,%203956%20*%202%20*%20ASIN%28SQRT%28POWER%28SIN%28RADIANS%2845.5200077%20-%20lat%29/%202%29,%202%29%20+%20COS%28RADIANS%2845.5200077%29%29%20*%20COS%28RADIANS%28lat%29%29%20*%20POWER%28SIN%28RADIANS%28-122.6942014%20-%20lng%29/2%29,2%29%29%29%20AS%20distance%20from%20%60stops%60%20order%20by%20%60distance%60,%20%60route%60%20asc%29%20as%20p%20group%20by%20%60route%60,%20%60dir%60%20order%20by%20%60distance%60%20asc%20limit%2010%22}

And the response:

> {"MYSQL_ERRNO" : 1064 , "MYSQL_ERROR" : "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(RADIANS(45.5200077)) * COS(RADIANS(lat)) * POWER(SIN(RADIANS(-122.6942014 - lng' at line 1" , "SERVER" : "trimet"}

Thanks!

Comment: Mary mother of God, what the hell is that

Comment: Not the prettiest of queries, I know. But it is my first pass :) .

Comment: "it just seemed really cool to have a JSON-speaking DB layer that all our scriptable content could talk to." and "MySQL adapter (others possible in the future)".  enough said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible immediate source of your problem is the URL encoding.  I see the plus operator is transmitted as-is.  That's dangerous, because `+` used to mean *space* in the traditional encoding.  http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738

Comment: This was it! I swapped the encodeURI for encodeURIComponent (didn't know about that one) and this did the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
...distance%60%20asc%20...
```

How are you escaping the sql? Looks like you're missing the "route", so the above reads "distance, asc". Looks like it goes downhill from there.

Comment: object = {SQL: "the query"};

request = connection.request('GET', '/db?' + encodeURI(JSON.stringify(object)), {'host': this.host})

Comment: The part I pulled out may not be the problem (though it's really hard to read through all the escaped codes), but if the unescaped version works after you manually decode it, then the decoder isn't doing the conversion correctly. Or at least I'd start on that assumption. If that's not it, then it's likely a bug in dbslayer. If it's not that, then it's just MySQL hating you for issuing that query ;)

Comment: The "+" could totally be it! That should be a "%2B".